# how to send key's to any application that is currently running from background program (c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, background, shortcut

my question is how to send some key's to any application from application that is running in background? Let's say that I made shortcut to LEFT ARROW key which is ALT+S, and than I want whenever I'm in any application and when I press ALT+S that background application response that shortcut and send to currently opened program LEFT ARROW key.
Here is a code that I made in Embarcadero c++ 2010 to simulate arrow left when pressing alt+s every 200 milisecond's:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
{
     bool bBothPressed = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)  && GetAsyncKeyState(0x53);
    if(bBothPressed){
        // ShowMessage("control!");
        keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

... and this work fine for my application, but what I want to know is how to include that code for global scope (any application), not just for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly encourage you to use [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of GetAsyncKeyState. That way you won't need a loop nor a Timer, thus making your application more reliable and responsive.

To simulate the keypresses to another application/window, you need to:

**A)** Focus the specific window:

```
BringWindowToTop(hwnd);
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
SetFocus(hwnd);
```

**B)** Send the keydown + keyup events:

```
keybd_event(keycode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
keybd_event(keycode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

This should suffice. However, keep in mind the user might be already pressing one of the keys you're *simulating*, thus the result might not be what you're expecting. To avoid that, you need to check if the keys are already being pressed (use GetAsyncKeyState here), then send a keyup before doing **B**.

**UPDATE:**

If you wish to send the keypresses to whatever application is currently on the foreground (being focused), you can skip **A**.

Comment: The main point is how to make application that run in background like service and wait when is ALT+S is pressed, and when is pressed that execute some command, in this case just ARROW LEFT, main thing is that shortcut alt+s must be executed like arrow left in any application. What I want to make is something like macro who is activate when alt+s is pressed. I know how to make handle to some particular application, but what I need here is that the alt+s shortcut have to be handled to every process which is currently opened.

Comment: thnx man your answer is very helpful I'm beginner in programing so my testing will take a little time :), but theoretically this is it what I searching for ...:)

Answer (score 0):

[SendInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) looks like it may be useful to you.

Comment: in this case sendinput is good function for sending shortcut to another application, and i know how to handle it to particular application (like handle it to notepad), but is there some function that can be handled to all application, without specifying every application?